# Where can I find the tests made to verify the functions in the python standard library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, github, standard-library

I am currently in a group project in school. We are using the python standard-library, and we are wondering if it has been tested by the python team. In other words, is there any documentation or open source `unit tests` for the entire python standard-library, and if so, where can we read more about this?

Comment: [https://github.com/python/cpython#testing](https://github.com/python/cpython#testing)

Comment: Of course there are tests. Releasing a project of such a scale without tests would be ridiculous. https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/b21d155f57d284aecf9092a9bd24258293965c2f/Lib/test

Comment: Also see the [Python Developer's Guide](https://devguide.python.org/), which (IIRC… I haven't read through the whole thing in a long time…) includes sections on using the test suite, how to create unit tests for new features, and even the results of a code-coverage scan for unit tests that they run periodically (although you may not be able to run the same scan yourself for free).

Comment: @Aran-Fey , using words like "ridiculous" is rude and condescending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it is.  They are located in the [Lib/test](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/test) directory of the CPython Github repository.

They are prefixed so that, for example, the `abc` module is named `test_abc.py`.